# How to select the imported module on IntelliSense?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Is there any way to select which module VSC imports when I use intellisense? In other words:

- I have module A and module B, which both export the function `ask()`
- How can I tell VSC to import module B's implementation of `ask()`?

Comment: You mean to disable one of the sources from auto suggestions, right?

Comment: Not necessarily @DoğancanArabacı